# What happens to contents when a list<T> is assigned to another list<T> variable?

Tags: c++

I have a `list<Myobj>` source which contains some `Myobj` instances, if I assign it to an empty `list<MyObj>` target what exactly happens in terms of contents?

Are `Myobj` instances duplicated in target via shallow copy? is the copy contructor called? or are they not duplicated at all?

Comment: The copy constructor will be called for each object. Whether that performs a shallow or deep copy is up to the implementation. Also obligatory nitpick: you probably don't need a `list`. Consider using a `vector` instead.

Comment: @AndreiTita: `Also obligatory nitpick: you probably don't need a list. Consider using a vector instead` That seems like rather a dangerous generalisation, don't you think?

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that a list<T> stores actual elements of T, not just pointers to them.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel Well, I figured out someone was going to say it anyway and I was in a write-y mood. And also, if someone actually uses a `list` in one of the rare cases which calls for the use of a `list`, that person is smart enough to know what the hell they are doing, anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the objects in the first list are copied into the second list. It is better not to think about "shallow" and "deep" copying here. The elements are copied, and the "depth" of the copy depends on what the class' copy constructor or assignment operator do. If your type T were a plain pointer, then the pointers would get copied, but not what they point to. There is no special magic going on.

Note that there are some subtleties which depend on what the source, or RHS of the assignment is (thanks to @mooingduck for reminding me of this). In C++11, there are situations in which the contents of the RHS could be *moved* into the LHS, in which case there is no copying at all.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am assuming this "source" list is indeed an lvalue.

Comment: @MooingDuck: So what is the other thing (not lvalue) and I assume that this is leading to move operation?

Answer (score 3):

After the assignment, the left-hand side is semantically equivalent to what the right-hand side was before the assignment, provided the type `Myobj` is sufficiently sane (e.g. its copy constructors and assignment operators also satisfy this if it's a class type).

Comment: While accurate, that's a very technical-sounding sentence.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Well, I could have said "they're the same", but I had a feeling that the OP knew this.